# How to force close a urllib connection?

Tags: python, connection, urllib, urlopen

I was looking at urllib in python and I was wondering is it possible to force close urllib.request.urlopen if the connection seems to be taking too long.

Comment: `urlopen()` has a `timeout` arg.

Comment: @Blurp please answer in answers

Comment: @ppperry There's a reason I didn't write an answer

Comment: what do you mean by "taking too long"? `timeout` argument of `urlopen` is not for overall request time.